# Connection Time Out Error Loading Image from Big Data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, bigdata

I have Image Gallery that photos are loaded using post method on document ready function in ASP.NET application. Photos are stored in big data. I retrieve all image paths and binding each image source. I am using Nanogallery js plugin to show photos. 
There is no error while retrieving data from bigdata but while loading photos, connection time out error occurs.

I tired for both 100 photos and 2 photos but results are same. I got same error.

Post Method

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            url: 'PhotoAlbum.aspx/GetAllPhotos',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                var arraydata = JSON.parse(data.d);
                loadGalery(arraydata);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
```

,

```
function loadGalery(pdata) {
            jQuery("#nanoGalleryHome").nanoGallery({ 
                items: pdata,
                thumbnailHoverEffect:'imageInvisible,imageScale150,borderLighter',
                viewerDisplayLogo:true,
                locationHash:false,
                thumbnailDisplayInterval: 5,
                thumbnailDisplayTransition: true,
                thumbnailLabel : { position : 'overImageOnBottom', display : true, displayDescription : true, titleMaxLength : 0, descriptionMaxLength : 0, hideIcons : false, title : '', itemsCount : '' },
                galleryRenderStep: 50,
                paginationDots : true,
                galleryFullpageButton:true
            });

        }

    });
```

Error Message: 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
http://BigDataPath/images/2015/3689500b-daa8-4a0b-81dd-7433d6304dfe?op=OPEN&user.name=web&namenoderpcaddress=bdm:8020&offset=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Problem was that 50075 port was closed so I opened the port and photos were loaded perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It would ne nice to have a live URL to check your issue.